# Adding computer to LogonWorkstation for user without overwriting previous Workstations

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am using this command

```
 Set-ADUser xyz -LogonWorkstations "$sysName1,$sysName1"
```

If i add third system to xyz user, then previous system gets overwritten by third system. I want to add third system along with these two systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `LogonWorkstations` property is a comma seperated string, so you can get its value and then add the new workstation to this before assigning it.

```
$User = "xyz"
$NewWorkstation = "Workstation03"

$LogonWorkstations = Get-AdUser -Identity $User -Properties LogonWorkstations | select -ExpandProperty LogonWorkstations #get current computernames that user can access

if ($LogonWorkstations) {
    Set-ADUser -Identity $User -LogonWorkstations "$LogonWorkstations,$NewWorkstation" #add new workstation to existing entries
}
else { 
    Set-ADUser -Identity $User -LogonWorkstations $NewWorkstation #only add new workstation
}
```